# Android - Locate IP of WAMP Server on a Local Netwiok

Tags: android, wamp

Can someone help me? I'm currently doing a **Android Application** project.

But it was too late for me to know that **MYSQL** is not entirely compatible to **Android**.

I can't go back now. As the title said that I am using a **WAMP Server** to host my **MYSQL Database** on the Local netwok from a computer.

And as I read (*Correct me If I'm wrong*) that you need the actual **IP** of that computer to grab the data from the **WAMP Server**.

If at any given moment that the **IP** of the **Hosting Computer** changes, the **Android Application** won't be able to connect to the **MYSQL Database**.

> Is there anyway for you to get the **IP** of the **Hosting Computer** programtically?
>
> I tried by using the current **IP Address** of the device to get the **Network IP**.

**Example:**

**Device IP** is **192.168.1.2** and **Hosting Computer IP** is **192.168.20**, now we know that the **Network IP** is **192.168.1.1**. Then will loop from **192.168.1.2** until **192.168.1.254**, the loop will only break/stop if it got the response you needed. Then saves that **IP** to string.

```
public String isConnectedToServer(String url, int index) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    String result = "";
    for(int octet = 2; octet <= 254; octet++) {
        String compare = ""+octet;
        if(!compare.equals(url.substring(index + 1, url.length()))) {
            try {
                HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://" + url.substring(0, index + 1) + "" + octet + "/AVMSSv2").openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Application");
                con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");

                //Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "NETWORK CONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    result = "http://" + url.substring(0, index + 1) + "" + octet + "/AVMSSv2/pages/android.php";
                    break;
                } else {
                    result = "";
                }
                Log.w("APP", "Network");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Handle your exceptions
                //Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "NETWORK ERROR CONNECTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("APP", "Exception", e);
                result = "";
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

> The above code is just an example of mine but does not seem to work. And I already Used **AsyncTask**. Feel free to give me any suggestion.
>
> **P.S.** The problem is that I can't change to a different database. Because the current project is Multi-Platform. That's why I need to stick to MYSQL because this is what the other platform are currently Using.
>
> And I wish to stick to a **Dynamic Host of IP** as possible.

Comment: You need the IP address to connect to any server. The mysql jdbc driver for Android works fine, as far as I know

Comment: Your idea to try all possible ip's is ok. That should work. Look carefull when the code tries the right one. Why would it go wrong then? But then you dont show us how you construct the ips in your url. So there is little to say or help.

Comment: If the device has ip .2 then do not start your loop with the .2. If your device is the .13 then loop from .2 to .255 but omit the .13.

Answer (score 0):

Use your router to set a static IP address of the database server.

Then you solve two problems. 1) it won't change IP addresses and 2) don't need to worry about programming anything like above as you'll know the IP address

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but is there anyway to acquire the IP by sticking to Dynamic Host IP.

Comment: Using DHCP? Why? There is no disadvantage to using a static IP in a LAN. Matter of fact, servers **should** have static IPs

Comment: I'm just asking because this kind is off bugging me for weeks now. At first I was using a static IP but I think you are right this might give some security issues if I stick to DHCP. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Security issues? No.. Just availability. There is no data confidentiality or integrity you need to worry about